# Error checking database <weird chars> File does not exist

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

After a server crash, I get a weird problem concerning database fixup. The console constantly throws a block of errors "Error checking database  File does not exist" I did not find any databases with these names.

Here is an image as I am notz allowed to directly include pics:
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CA87BQfUcAA21Cq.png:large

1. Where does domino know which databases to fixup?
2. How may I get rid of these errors?

Any idea appreciated.

Rene

Comment: Delete the dbdirman.nsf and restart the server...

Comment: Thanks Torsten, I guess that did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I found a clue, myself:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO78425

So, my next steps were fixup -j & compact on command line level without the server being up. Also, I deleted the dbdirman.nsf as suggested by Torsten.

I stumbled over a corrrupt database which caused a crash of the fixup. After moving the DB and recreating it from backup, the server could be started without an issue.

For now, the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem. For future reference, questions about Domino server problems like this should be posted on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow. StackOverflow is intended for programnming questions.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, Richard.